# Как соединить два и более std::stringstream

Tags: c++

Возможно ли записать два и/или более std::stringstream в один?

Подобие:

```
std::stringstream a;
std::stringstream b;
std::stringstream c;

a << b << c;
```

Comment: `a << b.str(); a<< c.str()` ?

Comment: ну или сделать `std::stringstream& operator <<(std::stringstream& in, const std::stringstream&s){return in << s.str();}`

Comment: можно даже менять местами состояние  stringstream& operator <<(stringstream& s1,  stringstream& s2)  {   s1.swap(s2);    return s1; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператора << одного потока в другой нет... но зато определен стандартный оператор записи буфера потока, т.е.

```
a << b.rdbuf() << c.rdbuf();
```

должно работать для любых протоков. Ну для конкретно `std::stringstream` воспользуйтесь кодом из первого комментария, так понятнее смотрится.